# Does anybody know anything about a Digital rtVAX 300?

Tags: cpu

I have this cpu that I know nothing about. One of my dad's friends gave it to me when he was clearing out his garage. It is very big and I think it is to a big computer, but I honestly have no idea. If someone could just give me an idea what it is for, how much it is worth, or if it can even be used for anything it would help me a lot. Thanks in advance. Here is what it looks like:

[image: http://www.tiffe.de/images/KAV30-AD-1.jpg]

Comment: Did you try Google since you clearly have at least some identifying information about the piece?

Comment: As is the question is a little broad. There's just so many elements from 'how do I power this system' to 'how to I communicate with this system'.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.dec/ZZTYdQuM9pA seems to be of interest, as would the link renan posted. 

There's a few additional bits of information which would be of use in working out what this is - the rtvaxen seem to be daughter cards for a PC or Vax system - I don't see any interfaces I recognise (or for that matter any ISA or MCI style connectors. Identifying these might help hugely

Comment: Old but some systems using it are still around. Refurbished spares are available from Pinnacle Micro (http://www.pinnaclemicro.com/computer/parts.php?m=DEC+Digital+Equipment+Corp&s=300+Boards+cpu+rtvax)

Comment: VME bus connectors along the button of the picture, would have to see the front connectors to tell or guess at what they are.

Comment: I used to work on VAX systems but it was a long time ago and that picture doesn't ring any bells, apart from the faceplate and backplane connectors. There are companies out there that still sell refurbished parts, just google "refurbished DEC VAX". If you are interested in selling it then contact one of them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a single-board computer or part of a bigger system. From [here](http://www.tiffe.de/Robotron/PDP-VAX/VAX/RTVAX300.PDF):

> The rtVAX 300 is a realtime target processor that is adaptable to running applications that benefit from a fully supported network connection.

Documentation on it seems to be quite scarce, so I guess you just have a museum piece.

Answer (score 1):

Actually from the comments, there's pretty much enough information to positively ID this part. Its a KAV30 - it says so on the bottom of the connector, and you can [find a manual](http://odl.sysworks.biz/disk$cddoc04mar21/decw$book/d474aaa5.decw$book) for it here. Its a daughtercard using a [VME bus connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMEbus). The *other* [installation manual](http://h30266.www3.hp.com/masterindex/installation_guide/installation_guide_0000863b.txt) I found states that requirements for installing a KAV30 are

```
1.1.1 Software Requirements

      You must have the following software on the system:

      o  VMS Version 5.0 or higher

      o  VAXELN Version 4.3

1.1.2 Hardware Requirements

      You must have either a hardcopy or a video terminal. Use
      the terminal to communicate with the operating system and
      to respond to installation prompts
```

I have no idea what the hardware requirements actually mean however, and interestingly it does not mention the VME bus connector at all.

The two manuals should give you a overview of what this is, well other than a museum piece.

Answer (score 1):

The KAV30 was DIGITAL's VAX single board computer using VMEbus form factor.
It was based on the rtVAX300 CPU hybrid which DIGITAL also sold to OEM.

The KAV30 does include 64MB memory, Ethernet and SCSI controller, 2 serial lines and a bridge to the VMEbus back plane.

DIGITAL did not build the KAV30 itself. It was developed and produced by CES Switzerland for DIGITAL.

It was mainly used with DIGITAL's VAXELN real time operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Looks just like the CPU card used in FISHER PROVOX VME consoles.  This card can be value to factories still running on this legacy control system. If you have no need for it you can contact a company called PCO.  www.pco2.com They refurbish and sell these.  They may be interested in it.